# Error 2007 - SQLyog

Tags: sqlyog

Good Morning,

I am trying to connect to a Mysql Data base using SqlYog, I have created a new connection and I have entered all the necessary informations (login,password & port). But when I click “ok”, I get this error message (Error 2007 : Protocol mismatch; server version = 1, client version = 10) . I have pinged the data base and it responds me successfully !!!

Could you please tell me how can I solve this problem, I need to access to the data base urgently.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually due to using a very old MySQL server (before 3.22.x) which has a different protocol version.

You can take a look at this [link](http://faq.webyog.com/content/1/178/en/sqlyog-is-a-client-for-the-mysql-server-_-but-what-server-versions-are-supported.html) to see what all server versions are supported.

To check your server protocol version, go to the MySQL command line and type:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"
```

SQLyog supports only the protocol version 10.

Comment: Thanks Jan S for your answer, i have contacted the db administrator : he told me that the type of DB isn't MySQL but ObjectStore !
Did you have an idea about this DB and it is possible to connect to it via PHP ?

Comment: Googling online found http://media.progress.com/realtime/techsupport/documentation/crystal/crystal13/customcd/OStore/6.3/doc/pdf/mo/mo.pdf
but i personally do not have any experience with ObjectStore